# How can I click on a pop-up Calendar wizard in Selenium 2?

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium 2 for a project which allows for date selection using jsf calendar wizard from myfaces (jsf 1.1). Can some one help me the steps for date selection. Thank you in advance.

**Date of Birht field screenshot**

[image]

**Calendar popup screenshot**

[image]

**Corresponding html being generated**

```
    <div class="content">
      <input id="firstApplicant2:ApplicantContent-DateOfBirth" name="firstApplicant2:ApplicantContent-DateOfBirth" type="text" maxlength="10" class="dateStyle" onfocus="selectText('null', 'firstApplicant2:ApplicantContent-DateOfBirth')" onclick="selectText('null', 'firstApplicant2:ApplicantContent-DateOfBirth')"><span id="firstApplicant2:ApplicantContent-DateOfBirthSpan"></span>
      <div id="firstApplicant2:ApplicantContent-DateOfBirthSpan_calendarDiv" class="jscalendar-DB-div-style" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <span id="firstApplicant2:ApplicantContent-DateOfBirthSpan"></span>
        <table style="width:250px;" class="jscalendar-DB-table-style">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="jscalendar-DB-title-background-style">
              <td>
                <table style="width:248px;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="jscalendar-DB-title-style">
                        <span><span class="jscalendar-DB-title-control-normal-style"> <img src="/webapp/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.MyFacesResourceLoader/13080856/calendar.HtmlCalendarRenderer/DB/left1.gif" width="10px" height="11px" style="border:0px;">  </span><span class="jscalendar-DB-title-control-normal-style"> <img src="/webapp/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.MyFacesResourceLoader/13080856/calendar.HtmlCalendarRenderer/DB/right1.gif" width="10px" height="11px" style="border:0px;">  </span>  </span>
                      </td>
                      <td style="text-align:right;">
                        <a href="#"></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="jscalendar-DB-body-style"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="jscalendar-DB-today-style">
              <td class="jscalendar-DB-today-lbl-style">
                <span>Today is <a class="jscalendar-DB-today-style" title="Go To Current Month" href="#">06/15/2011</a></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="firstApplicant2:ApplicantContent-DateOfBirthSpan_selectMonthDiv" class="jscalendar-DB-div-style" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
      <div id="firstApplicant2:ApplicantContent-DateOfBirthSpan_selectYearDiv" class="jscalendar-DB-div-style" style="visibility: hidden;"></div><script type="text/javascript">
firstApplicant2_3AApplicantContent_2DDateOfBirthCalendarVar=new org_apache_myfaces_PopupCalendar();
      firstApplicant2_3AApplicantContent_2DDateOfBirthCalendarVar.initData.imgDir = "/webapp/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.MyFacesResourceLoader/13080856/calendar.HtmlCalendarRenderer/DB/";
      firstApplicant2_3AApplicantContent_2DDateOfBirthCalendarVar.initData.monthName = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
      firstApplicant2_3AApplicantContent_2DDateOfBirthCalendarVar.initData.dayName = new Array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat");
      firstApplicant2_3AApplicantContent_2DDateOfBirthCalendarVar.initData.startAt = 0;
      firstApplicant2_3AApplicantContent_2DDateOfBirthCalendarVar.dateFormatSymbols.weekdays = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
      firstApplicant2_3AApplicantContent_2DDateOfBirthCalendarVar.dateFormatSymbols.shortWeekdays = new Array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat");
      firstApplicant2_3AApplicantContent_2DDateOfBirthCalendarVar.dateFormatSymbols.shortMonths = new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
      firstApplicant2_3AApplicantContent_2DDateOfBirthCalendarVar.dateFormatSymbols.months = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
      firstApplicant2_3AApplicantContent_2DDateOfBirthCalendarVar.dateFormatSymbols.eras = new Array("BC","AD");
      firstApplicant2_3AApplicantContent_2DDateOfBirthCalendarVar.dateFormatSymbols.ampms = new Array("AM","PM");
      firstApplicant2_3AApplicantContent_2DDateOfBirthCalendarVar.initData.todayDateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
      firstApplicant2_3AApplicantContent_2DDateOfBirthCalendarVar.initData.popupLeft = false;

      firstApplicant2_3AApplicantContent_2DDateOfBirthCalendarVar.init(document.getElementById('firstApplicant2:ApplicantContent-DateOfBirthSpan'));
      </script><img src="/webapp/Images/upgrade/icon_calendar.jpg" style="vertical-align:bottom;" onclick="firstApplicant2_3AApplicantContent_2DDateOfBirthCalendarVar._popUpCalendar(this,document.getElementById('firstApplicant2:ApplicantContent-DateOfBirth'),'MM/dd/yyyy')">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable to just update the input text field with the properly formatted date? Unless you are specifically testing that MyFaces widget, I think this should suffice.